# Editar sugestões do input

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, input, google

Oi, gostaria de saber algum modo de editar as sugestões do input exp: quando o usuário escrever alguma coisa no input nas sugestões dele mostrar os resultados da solicitação pelo ajax para ele poder selecionar com as setas direcionais( cima ou baixo ), tipo o que o google faz quando iniciamos uma pesquisa.

Comment: Você quer um `autocomplete`?

Comment: Essas "sugestões" que pretende mostrar vem do banco, certo? Quantos registros no total seriam?

Comment: Não tem um limite de registros pre definido, quando o usuário digitar alguma coisa os caracteres digitados no input são usados para iniciar uma filtragem no banco de dados, assim quando ele digita mostra as opções e quanto mais ele digita mais filtrado e o resultado para que no final fique só o que ele procurou, quero colocar os resultados como uma sugestão do input para que quando ele ver a palavra que quer usar só use os direcionais cima ou baixo para selecionar a palavra desejada.

Comment: Entendi. É que o auto-complete faz isso, e pensei em criar toda lista de uma vez no código da página e nessa lista que será feita a consulta, em vez de ficar enviando requisições consecutivas ao banco cada vez que digita uma letra.